# How to navigate to other page in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, url, routes, angular6

Im trying to redirect my page from login to another page. Im following this code.

My login component ts file:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {
}

funLogin(mobilenumber){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('registration');
}
```

In my html Im calling this function in a submit btn,

```
<button class="common-btn btn" (click)="funLogin(mobileNo.value)">Submit</button>

In my app.login.routing file,
 export const loginRouting: Routes = [
{
 path: '', component: DashboardRootComponent, canActivateChild: [],
    children: [
        { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent },
    ]
   }
  ]
```

I have tried with "this.router.navigate" & referredlot of links. But it didnt work. Can anyone please tell me where Im going wrong or if you could give me a workingh sample it would be better.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you try the code above?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

@sasi.. try like this,

```
 <a routerLink="/registration"><button class="btn btn-success" > Submit </button></a>
```

**Update :**

In order to use the routing in your application, you must register the components which allows the angular router to render the view.

We need register our components in `App Module` or any `Feature Module` of it (your current working module) in order to route to specific component view.

We can register components in two ways

1. [`.forRoot(appRoutes)`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forRoot) for app level component registration like
   `featuteModules`(ex. UserManagement) and `components` which you want register at `root level`.
2. [`.forChild(featureRoutes)`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forChild) for feature modules `child components`(Ex. UserDelete, UserUpdate).

   you can register something like below,

   ```
     const appRoutes: Routes = [
         { path: 'user', loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule' },
         { path: 'heroes', component: HeroListComponent },
      ];

     @NgModule({
       imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       FormsModule,
       RouterModule.forRoot(
         appRoutes
       )
     ],
   ```

> **P.S :** In order to navigate from one component to another, you must include the **[`RouterModule`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule)** in corresponding Module Imports array from `@angular/router` package.

You can navigate one to another page in Angular in Two ways. (both are same at wrapper level but the implementation from our side bit diff so.)

> ***[routerLink directive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description)***

**`routerLink`** directive gives you absolute path match like `navigateByUrl()` of **`Router`** class.

```
 <a [routerLink]=['/registration']><button class="btn btn-success" > Submit </button></a>
```

If you use `dynamic values` to generate the link, you can pass an `array` of path segments, followed by the `params` for each segment.

For instance **`routerLink=['/team', teamId, 'user', userName, {details: true}]`** means that we want to generate a link to [`/team/11/user/bob;details=true`](https://angular.io).

There are some useful points to be remembered when we are using **`routerLink`**.

- *If the first segment begins with **`/`**, the router will look up the route
  from the root of the app.*
- *If the first segment begins with **`./`**, or doesn't begin with a slash,
  the router will instead look in the children of the current activated
  route.*
- *And if the first segment begins with **`../`**, the router will go up one
  level.*

for more info have look here.. **[`routerLink`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)**

> ***[Router class](https://angular.io/api/router/Router)***

We need inject **`Router`** class into the component in order to use it's methods.

There more than two methods to navigate like `navigate()` , `navigateByUrl()`, and some other.. but we will mostly use these two.

1. **[`navigate()`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) :**

   > Navigate based on the provided array of commands and a starting point. If no starting route is provided, the navigation is absolute.

   ```
    this.route.navigate(['/team/113/user/ganesh']);
   ```

   **`navigate()`** command will append the latest string is append to existing URL. We can also parse the `queryParams` from this method like below,

   ```
    this.router.navigate(['/team/'], {
       queryParams: { userId: this.userId, userName: this.userName }
    });
   ```

   You can get the these values with **[`ActivatedRoute`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute)** in navigated Component. you can check here more about [`paramMap`](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action), [`snapshot(no-observable alternative)`](https://angular.io/guide/router#snapshot-the-no-observable-alternative).
2. **[`navigateByUrl()`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigatebyurl)**

   > Navigate based on the provided URL, which must be absolute.

   ```
    this.route.navigateByUrl(['/team/113/user/ganesh']);
   ```

   **`navigateByUrl()`** is similar to changing the location bar directly–we are providing the **whole** new URL.

Answer (score 23):

I am using angular 7 and I solved it in this way into my project.

1.First We need to implement this Modules to our app.module.ts file

```
import { AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule, 
    FormsModule,
  ],

})
```

2.Then Open your.component.html file and then fire a method for navigate where you want to go

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="gotoHome()">Home</button>
```

3.Then Go your.component.ts file for where you want to navigate. And add this code there.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class YourComponentClassName implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    gotoHome(){
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);  // define your component where you want to go
    }

}
```

4.And lastly want to say be careful to look after your app-routing.module.ts
where you must have that component path where you want to navigate otherwise it will give you error. For my case.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'', component:LoginComponent},
  { path: 'home', component:HomeComponent },  // you must add your component here
  { path: '**', component:PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Thanks I think, I share all of the case for this routing section. Happy Coding !!!

Comment: <button [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</button>

Answer (score 2):

navigateByUrl expects an absolute path, so a leading / might take you to the right page

You could also use navigate and don't need the leading / but the syntax is slightly different as it expects an array for the path

https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigateByUrl

Answer (score 2):

```
<a class="nav-link mt-1" [routerLink]="['/login']"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Login</a>
```